# How to pass variable as ARG or KWARG in my get_success_url

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have been working all afternoon to try and pass a variable to a get_success_url to show the correct record after I process an UpdateView.  I am using class based views, and I am trying to update a record and then show the corresponding update record in a different view.  However, when I am passing the pk, it works but it's not the right one.

Essentially, here is the code in question...

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse_lazy('Book:create_new_author_detail', kwargs={ 'pk' : self.object.pk })
```

The above would work fine and does in many scenarios.  However, in this case, I am trying to pass a specific pk that does not align with this particular updateview.

I have tried something like....

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse_lazy('Book:create_new_author_detail', kwargs={ 'pk' : self.object.new_author.pk })
```

Perhaps something like....

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse_lazy('Book:create_new_author_detail', kwargs={ 'pk' : self.object.pk, 'new_author' : self.new_author.id  })
```

Would work?  I can get the pk using this code, just not the right one.  I want to reference new_author.id so that the reverse_lazy picks the right pk.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Comment: `return reverse_lazy('Book:create_new_author_detail', kwargs={ 'pk' : self.object.new_author.pk })` should work if object has new_author, but `return reverse_lazy('Book:create_new_author_detail', kwargs={ 'pk' : self.object.pk, 'new_author' : self.new_author.id  })` won't work as view does not have any attribute named `new_author`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A night of sleep helps I guess....

Here's what I came up with.....

```
def get_success_url(self):
    book= Author.objects.filter(author_id=self.object.pk).first()
    return reverse_lazy('Author:author_view', kwargs={ 'pk' : book.pk })
```